# Jquery mobile theme is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm adding LI dynamically on a ul by using jquery but the jquery mobile theme is not applying.

here is my code

```
 $('#employee_list').on("click", "a", function() {
            var li_id = this.id;            

            $("#chart").html(" ");
            var title = '<li id="visited"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">True</a>';
            $("#main_child_ul").append(title);
            $('#org').trigger("create");



            $("#org").jOrgChart({
                chartElement : '#chart',
                dragAndDrop  : true
            });
            //$("#orgger").collapsibleset();

        });
```

and here is the html

```
<ul  id="org" style="display:none">
            <li id="visited"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">True</a>
               <ul id="main_child_ul" class="children">

               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Any help? this is adding tree nodes dynamically but theme is not applying.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't enough to check for the problem. Where's the employee_list link? And your function is looking for a li with the same id, which isn't there and if it was, the markup would be invalid (ids need to be unique).

Comment: This is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jjLhQ/; provide a demo on jsfiddle to check your issue

Comment: You want to insert a collapsible set or a listview? You're nit using `data-role` attribute, without it, JQM can't apply styles.

Answer (score 0):

When you add items to a listview, you will have to call the refresh() method to update the styles for the items which are added.

Ex:

```
$('#org').listview('refresh');
```

Let me know if it works.

Thanks